# How do I call batchDelete() in Google Talent Solution for multiple jobs?

Tags: google-api-python-client, google-cloud-talent-solution

Google's [page on `batchDelete`](https://cloud.google.com/talent-solution/job-search/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.jobs/batchDelete) says that a `requisitionId` needs to be specified. As a `requisitionId` identifies a specific job, how can I call `batchDelete` to delete multiple jobs? Say, all the jobs of a specific company?

I need to do this purely to delete some test data.

Comment: did you ever get an answer for this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am also trying to figure this out...

Comment: No. But because I had so few to delete I deleted them individually

Comment: Running into same issue (except I'm using google-api-ruby-client); seems like a fundamental bug on their part...really surprised there's not more discussion/replies from the community

Comment: I’ve requested paid support but had nothing back. I’m assuming developer support isn’t ingrained at Google.

Comment: Assuming no one has figured this out? Hitting this same issue.